# Keeping Track of our Site Stats

Tags: discussion, statistics

This post is now essentially obsolete; all these statistics are easily accessible through [this site](http://codemanteau.com/stacker/?siteId=225), which is run by [キルア](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/274/%E3%82%AD%E3%83%AB%E3%82%A2). I am still collecting data, but there's little reason to continue updating this page.

---

**Original post:**

I've been collecting stats from our [Area51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/31538/anime-manga) on a daily basis. These statistics are publicly available, but they have to be saved and compiled by hand because they're updated regularly.

These statistics will be updated <s>approximately once a week, probably on Monday mornings</s> **whenever someone bugs me enough to do so in chat**. The statistics are taken at approximately 0:30 UTC, though I may be as much as a few hours late (this shouldn't affect things drastically). I've also been collecting network-wide statistics from the [main Stack Exchange page](http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic), but I don't intend to publish those here because that's around 700 numbers per day, of which only a very small amount is relevant to us. You can message me on chat if you need some of that data.

The daily statistics have a lot of noise, but there is an advantage over weekly ones. Since the traffic per day is the median over a 2-week period, it is possible with a pretty strong degree of certainty to conclude approximately what the traffic was on any given day. If the traffic drops, then the traffic on that day must be lower than what is reported, and if it increases it must be higher than what is reported. If it stays the same we can't conclude anything. However, if all you want is a broad overview, I've also included a summary first by taking only Monday statistics.

If there are other numbers you want to see which I'm not posting, feel free to request them.

---

**WEEKLY STATISTICS**

```
  Date           Qs/day  %Ans    Visits/day     A. ratio     Total users    Avid users
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  2013-02-11     5.6     89       257            1.6          442            56
  2013-02-18     4.2     89       280            1.6          468            58
  2013-02-25     4.9     89       272            1.5          489            61
  2013-03-04     5.0     89       307            1.5          517            64
  2013-03-11     5.1     89       319            1.5          547            69
  2013-03-18     4.6     90       319            1.5          571            71
  2013-03-25     4.6     89       337            1.5          595            75
  2013-04-01     5.4     89       393            1.5          623            83
  2013-04-08     6.4     89       368            1.5          648            85
  2013-04-15     6.4     89       358            1.5          666            85
  2013-04-22     5.4     89       360            1.5          689            86
  2013-04-29     6.0     88       396            1.5          703            90
  2013-05-06     5.6     88       460            1.5          732            91
  2013-05-13     4.9     87       604            1.5          762            92
  2013-05-20     5.0     87       757            1.4          787            93
  2013-05-27     4.2     88       826            1.5          811            93
  2013-06-03     3.8     88       914            1.4          833            93
  2013-06-10     4.2     89      1043            1.4          869            97
  2013-06-17     3.6     89      1119            1.5          888            97
  2013-06-24     3.1     89      1169            1.4          911            98
  2013-07-01     3.5     89      1335            1.4          939           102
  2013-07-08     3.1     89      1394            1.4          964           102
  2013-07-15     2.9     90      1419            1.4          993           106
  2013-07-22     3.0     90      1585            1.5         1027           109
  2013-07-29     3.3     90      1768            1.5         1065           114
  2013-08-05     5.1     90      1875            1.5         1118           122
  2013-08-12     6.7     90      1985            1.5         1161           134
  2013-08-19     6.1     91      2049            1.5         1200           141
```

**DAILY STATISTICS**

```
  Date           Qs/day  %Ans    Visits/day     A. ratio     Total users    Avid users
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  2013-02-11     5.6     89       257            1.6          442            56
  2013-02-12     5.4     89       262            1.6          448            56
  2013-02-13     5.4     89       270            1.6          456            56
  2013-02-14     4.9     90       277            1.5          459            56
  2013-02-15     4.0     90       281            1.6          464            56
  2013-02-16     4.3     89       280            1.6          467            57
  2013-02-17     4.2     89       280            1.6          467            57
  2013-02-18     4.2     89       280            1.6          468            58
  2013-02-19     4.3     90       275            1.6          470            59
  2013-02-20     4.0     89       272            1.6          470            59
  2013-02-21     4.2     89       274            1.6          475            60
  2013-02-22     4.2     89       270            1.6          478            60
  2013-02-23     4.9     89       272            1.6          484            60
  2013-02-24     5.2     89       284            1.6          487            61
  2013-02-25     4.9     89       272            1.5          489            61
  2013-02-26     5.0     89       272            1.5          492            61
  2013-02-27     5.0     89       280            1.5          496            61
  2013-02-28     5.2     89       280            1.5          500            61
  2013-03-01     5.5     89       286            1.5          507            62
  2013-03-02     5.1     90       290            1.5          509            63
  2013-03-03     4.9     90       301            1.5          511            63
  2013-03-04     5.0     89       307            1.5          517            64
  2013-03-05     5.4     89       309            1.5          522            64
  2013-03-06     5.7     89       311            1.5          525            65
  2013-03-07     5.7     90       313            1.5          532            66
  2013-03-08     5.8     90       313            1.5          537            67
  2013-03-09     5.2     90       316            1.5          540            68
  2013-03-10     5.1     89       320            1.5          544            69
  2013-03-11     5.1     89       319            1.5          547            69
  2013-03-12     5.0     90       320            1.5          551            69
  2013-03-13     4.7     90       323            1.5          555            70
  2013-03-14     4.4     91       323            1.5          559            71
  2013-03-15     4.7     90       318            1.5          562            71
  2013-03-16     4.4     90       318            1.5          565            71
  2013-03-17     4.4     90       319            1.5          568            71
  2013-03-18     4.6     90       319            1.5          571            71
  2013-03-19     4.3     90       323            1.5          574            72
  2013-03-20     4.0     90       323            1.5          576            75
  2013-03-21     4.2     89       323            1.5          578            75
  2013-03-22     4.6     89       319            1.5          582            75
  2013-03-23     4.3     89       321            1.5          585            75
  2013-03-24     4.3     89       332            1.5          592            75
  2013-03-25     4.6     89       337            1.5          595            75
  2013-03-26     5.1     88       343            1.5          598            76
  2013-03-27     5.1     89       368            1.5          601            76
  2013-03-28     5.3     89       393            1.5          605            78
  2013-03-29     5.3     89       387            1.5          610            80
  2013-03-30     5.4     89       393            1.5          615            82
  2013-03-31     5.6     89       393            1.5          618            83
  2013-04-01     5.4     89       393            1.5          623            83
  2013-04-02     7.1     88       387            1.5          632            83
  2013-04-03     7.2     88       400            1.5          636            84
  2013-04-04     7.1     88       392            1.5          638            84
  2013-04-05     6.6     88       382            1.5          640            85
  2013-04-06     6.6     89       375            1.5          644            85
  2013-04-07     6.8     89       375            1.5          646            85
  2013-04-08     6.4     89       368            1.5          648            85
  2013-04-09     6.2     89       363            1.5          650            85
  2013-04-10     6.6     89       363            1.5          655            85
  2013-04-11     6.6     89       362            1.5          659            85
  2013-04-12     6.6     88       362            1.5          661            85
  2013-04-13     6.4     89       358            1.5          663            85
  2013-04-14     6.3     89       358            1.5          664            85
  2013-04-15     6.4     89       358            1.5          666            85
  2013-04-16     4.8     89       349            1.5          670            85
  2013-04-17     4.4     88       349            1.5          675            85
  2013-04-18     4.3     89       349            1.5          678            85
  2013-04-19     4.6     89       349            1.5          680            85
  2013-04-20     4.6     89       358            1.5          683            85
  2013-04-21     5.3     89       360            1.5          686            85
  2013-04-22     5.4     89       360            1.5          689            86
  2013-04-23     5.1     89       366            1.5          692            86
  2013-04-24     4.8     90       366            1.5          693            87
  2013-04-25     4.6     90       377            1.5          697            87
  2013-04-26     4.4     90       377            1.5          698            87
  2013-04-27     4.6     90       385            1.5          698            88
  2013-04-28     5.4     89       390            1.5          700            90
  2013-04-29     6.0     88       396            1.5          703            90
  2013-04-30     5.9     88       402            1.5          707            90
  2013-05-01     6.1     88       410            1.5          710            90
  2013-05-02     5.9     89       428            1.5          712            90
  2013-05-03     5.6     89       443            1.5          720            90
  2013-05-04     5.9     89       448            1.5          722            90
  2013-05-05     5.6     88       455            1.5          724            90
  2013-05-06     5.6     88       460            1.5          732            91
  2013-05-07     5.6     88       464            1.5          736            91
  2013-05-08     5.9     88       477            1.5          743            92
  2013-05-09     5.8     88       477            1.5          747            92
  2013-05-10     5.9     88       519            1.5          751            92
  2013-05-11     5.6     88       553            1.5          758            92
  2013-05-12     5.2     87       562            1.5          760            92
  2013-05-13     4.9     87       604            1.5          762            92
  2013-05-14     5.1     88       662            1.5          767            92
  2013-05-15     5.0     88       684            1.5          772            92
  2013-05-16     5.0     88       702            1.5          774            92
  2013-05-17     4.9     88       723            1.5          777            92
  2013-05-18     4.8     88       740            1.4          780            93
  2013-05-19     4.7     87       757            1.4          783            93
  2013-05-20     5.0     87       757            1.4          787            93
  2013-05-21     5.4     87       766            1.4          791            93
  2013-05-22     5.1     87       772            1.4          794            93
  2013-05-23     5.1     88       780            1.4          799            93
  2013-05-24     4.8     88       806            1.4          804            93
  2013-05-25     4.9     88       824            1.5          807            93
  2013-05-26     4.7     88       826            1.5          810            93
  2013-05-27     4.2     88       826            1.5          811            93
  2013-05-28     4.3     88       830            1.5          816            93
  2013-05-29     4.2     88       853            1.5          820            93
  2013-05-30     4.4     88       874            1.5          822            93
  2013-05-31     4.6     89       877            1.5          825            93
  2013-06-01     4.2     89       890            1.5          828            93
  2013-06-02     4.0     89       906            1.4          831            93
  2013-06-03     3.8     88       914            1.4          833            93
  2013-06-04     3.9     89       936            1.4          837            93
  2013-06-05     4.1     88       982            1.4          843            93
  2013-06-06     4.2     88      1018            1.4          849            93
  2013-06-07     4.4     88      1033            1.4          855            94
  2013-06-08     4.2     89      1040            1.4          857            95
  2013-06-09     4.2     89      1040            1.4          864            96
  2013-06-10     4.2     89      1043            1.4          869            97
  2013-06-11     4.1     89      1053            1.4          871            97
  2013-06-12     3.9     89      1070            1.4          876            97
  2013-06-13     4.1     89      1062            1.4          879            97
  2013-06-14     4.1     89      1089            1.4          883            97
  2013-06-15     4.1     89      1100            1.4          886            97
  2013-06-16     3.9     89      1113            1.4          885            97
  2013-06-17     3.6     89      1119            1.5          888            97
  2013-06-18     3.5     89      1119            1.5          893            97
  2013-06-19     3.1     89      1119            1.5          898            97
  2013-06-20     3.3     89      1119            1.4          900            98
  2013-06-21     2.9     89      1140            1.4          905            98
  2013-06-22     3.1     89      1156            1.5          901            98
  2013-06-23     2.9     89      1163            1.5          905            98
  2013-06-24     3.1     89      1169            1.4          911            98
  2013-06-25     3.1     89      1186            1.5          915            98
  2013-06-26     3.4     89      1205            1.5          919            98
  2013-06-27     3.4     89      1226            1.4          923           100
  2013-06-28     3.4     89      1246            1.4          928           101
  2013-06-29     3.5     89      1260            1.4          935           102
  2013-06-30     3.4     90      1297            1.4          936           102
  2013-07-01     3.5     89      1335            1.4          939           102
  2013-07-02     3.3     90      1357            1.4          944           102
  2013-07-03     3.6     89      1386            1.4          945           102
  2013-07-04     3.3     90      1402            1.4          951           102
  2013-07-05     3.6     89      1402            1.4          954           102
  2013-07-06     3.4     89      1402            1.4          958           102
  2013-07-07     3.3     89      1394            1.4          961           102
  2013-07-08     3.1     89      1394            1.4          964           102
  2013-07-09     3.4     89      1394            1.4          971           102
  2013-07-10     3.3     89      1394            1.4          973           102
  2013-07-11     2.9     89      1398            1.4          980           103
  2013-07-12     2.9     90      1398            1.4          984           103
  2013-07-13     3.1     90      1398            1.5          988           105
  2013-07-14     3.0     90      1409            1.5          991           105
  2013-07-15     2.9     90      1419            1.4          993           106
  2013-07-16     2.7     90      1426            1.4          996           107
  2013-07-17     2.5     90      1441            1.5         1001           107
  2013-07-18     2.5     90      1478            1.5         1007           109
  2013-07-19     2.4     90      1516            1.5         1013           109
  2013-07-20     2.4     90      1526            1.5         1017           109
  2013-07-21     2.8     90      1555            1.5         1022           109
  2013-07-22     3.0     90      1585            1.5         1027           109
  2013-07-23     2.6     90      1610            1.5         1030           112
  2013-07-24     2.6     90      1660            1.5         1035           112
  2013-07-25     2.9     90      1687            1.5         1042           112
  2013-07-26     3.1     90      1691            1.5         1053           114
  2013-07-27     3.1     90      1697            1.5         1061           114
  2013-07-28     3.1     90      1733            1.5         1062           114
  2013-07-29     3.3     90      1768            1.5         1065           114
  2013-07-30     4.1     90      1782            1.5         1073           115
  2013-07-31     4.4     90      1808            1.5         1089           118
  2013-08-01     5.1     90      1842            1.5         1100           119
  2013-08-02     5.1     90      1867            1.5         1106           122
  2013-08-03     5.1     90      1871            1.5         1112           122
  2013-08-04     5.1     90      1873            1.5         1113           122
  2013-08-05     5.1     90      1875            1.5         1118           122
  2013-08-06     5.2     90      1875            1.5         1124           122
  2013-08-07     5.4     91      1882            1.5         1131           122
  2013-08-08     5.4     91      1892            1.5         1142           124
  2013-08-09     5.9     91      1913            1.5         1147           125
  2013-08-10     6.1     90      1955            1.5         1154           131
  2013-08-11     6.5     91      1982            1.5         1155           132
  2013-08-12     6.7     90      1985            1.5         1161           134
  2013-08-13     6.7     91      2004            1.5         1167           139
  2013-08-14     7.1     91      2004            1.5         1176           139
  2013-08-15     6.4     91      2004            1.5         1180           139
  2013-08-16     6.4     91      2049            1.5         1182           141
  2013-08-17     6.2     91      2049            1.5         1188           141
  2013-08-18     6.1     91      2049            1.5         1189           141
  2013-08-19     6.1     91      2049            1.5         1200           141
  2013-08-20     6.3     91      2033            1.5         1203           141
  2013-08-21     6.2     91      2062            1.5         1209           142
  2013-08-22     6.4     91      2017            1.5         1215           142
  2013-08-23     5.9     92      1985            1.5         1222           147
  2013-08-24     5.3     92      2017            1.5         1227           147
```

Thanks to user [F'x](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2700/fx) on Academia for the table design, which was used in [this post](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283/keeping-track-of-our-stats).

Comment: We *can* share those statistics if the numbers are public anyway. Ping any of us in chat. Only if it's public though!

Comment: @MadaraUchiha The difficulty is that historical stats are not public information anymore. By compiling this, I am essentially making it public. You might be able to share the stats anyway, but I wouldn't want you to have to update this post on a regular basis and it's worth having it available to everyone, so I'll keep doing this until it's not necessary anymore.

Comment: If you were able to get to those stats as a normal users (even if you had to put up some work for it), I can share it as a moderator. You can post the useful stuff here though, nothing preventing you from doing that! You already have my +1.

Comment: @LoganM If the stats are gained from analyzing the stats on Area51, there's no problem but moderators cannot share data that is only available to them because they're moderators.

Comment: @Alenanno I don't know exactly what stats moderators can see that I can't (nor do I care to know—the above statistics are sufficient for everything I need). If there's an easy way to pull up Area51 stats from the past, that might actually be useful and allowed. If they don't have access to that, then it's no different if the mods gather and post the stats or I do. In any case I'm fine gathering the stats and updating this post occasionally.